# How to call the index.php of mediawiki from a server with index.html file?

Tags: php, mediawiki

Recently I have installed a mediawiki for my lab.
 For that purpose I used one of our workstation as the host using Apache and Mysql.
 Now the issue is I want to link that wiki page in a webpage so that people can click on the webpage to redirec to  the wiki page. 
 while doing so it reveals my i.p. of the host workstation. 
Let me explain with example in short. My current wiki address is something like this:

```
http://123.456.78.90/labwiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

Which I want to convert into:

```
http://www.example.edu/~user/labwiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

Is it possible to do that without interfering with that domain. Because I don't have access to `www.example.edu`, rather I have access to `www.example.edu/~user`.

I hope, I am clear to explain my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [`$wgServer`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer) and [`$wgScriptPath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgScriptPath).

Comment: Could you please be so kind and explain, how to play around with these two settings. I know, these two settings determines the address for the localsetting.php file. But, my original question is how to play around with these two settings without changing much in the original installation.

Comment: okay, what other option I have got is to change the i.p. with a name based virtual host name ! Is it possible to meet with my requirement !!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You want to change the configuration of your wiki but not change it at the same time?

Comment: Okay, may be I was not clear. Let me briefly make it clear. How can I change
    http://123.456.78.90
to 
    http://wiki.mydomain.com

In the same server. Let's forget about the previous issue where I wanted to shift it to university server. But, if I am not wrong, I have learned that the i.p. can be replaced with a domain name of my choice. I have tried, but the domain name is not recognizing the i.p.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? That wiki.mydomain.com does not work or that it works but the links generated by the wiki software still point to 123.456.78.90?

Comment: I am adding my comment in fraction as it is too long

okay, here is what I did. I followed
[this one](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and [this one](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Apache_installation#Virtual_Hosts) to change the files in **/etc/apache2/vhosts.d** and created a **.conf** file mydomain.conf.

Comment: These are the changes
 `<VirtualHost 123.456.78.90:80><br/>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@labwiki<br/>
    ServerName wiki.mydomain.com<br/>
DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/labwiki/<br/>
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/labwiki">`<br/>
And I changed the listen.conf file in **/etc/apache2** to this
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 123.456.78.90:80

The changes I made in the LocalSettings.php file are
`$wgSitename = "labwiki";
$wgScriptPath = "/labwiki";
$wgServer = "http://wiki.mydomain.com";`

Comment: Now, the issue is when I type in the browser wiki.mydomain.com then it shows something like this **Login required From labwiki Jump to: navigation, search Please log in to view other pages. Retrieved from "wiki.mydomain.com/index.php/Special:Badtitle";** @Tgr

Comment: No, it still shows the i.p. rather than the domain name.